# Splitting std::vector of size m into vector of vectors of size n

Tags: c++

Given a vector `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]`,
what are some possible approaches to construct `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17]]`, focusing primarily on readability?

At the moment, I have correctly defined the starting and ending indexes of all the subarrays, and was trying to use `std::copy(cam.begin() + start, cam.begin() + end+ 1, vec.begin());` to construct a new vector.. resulting in:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Comment: In what way _best_? The fastest? The most readable? The most memory efficient? Without a clear definition of "good" this question is opinion based.

Comment: If you have a working program (the working part is a hard requirement) and can show a [mcve] of it, then consider posting on [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Maybe a better phrasing would be "what are some reasonable ways, and the pros and cons of each?"

Comment: @NateEldredge Probably you are right but I'm not in the position to rephrase the question. I'm just pointing to the problems. OP can fix them and improve the question.

Comment: The problem here is that if you ask ten C++ developers what is the best way to do X, you will get eleven different answers.

Comment: @NateEldredge yep absolutely, my bad, rephrased the question based on your comments, just looking for general approaches

Comment: What are `cam`, `end`, and `vec`? Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your failing program so we can see what’s going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just after some code that can split a vector into a vector of up-to-five-element vectors, this should do it. It's bigger than necessary only because of the test harness around it.

The "meat" of the code is the templated function `makeVecOfVecs()`, and the single-line call to it. It's quite handy to do this sort of thing as a template since it then becomes easy to extend to other data types. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// From a flat vector, construct a vector of sub-vectors, each of a
// specific size (except the last sub-vector, which may be smaller).

template<class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>>
makeVecOfVecs(
    const std::vector<T> &in,
    unsigned int sz
) {
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> out;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i += sz) {
        if (in.size() - i < sz)
            sz = in.size() - i;

        std::vector<T> newVec(sz);
        std::copy(in.begin() + i, in.begin() + i + sz, newVec.begin());
        out.push_back(newVec);

        // As pointed out in a comment, you could probably
        // replace the three preceding lines with just:
        //    out.emplace_back(in.begin() + i, in.begin() + i + sz);
        // and avoid creating newVec.
    }

    return out;
}

// Test harness for the above function.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Default to 17 values, allow for override. Could probably
    // make more robust, but is IS only test code.

    int count = 17;
    if (argc > 1)
        count = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Input data for testing, print for validation.

    std::vector<int> in;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        in.push_back(i + 1);
    std::cout << "\nInput (" << count << "):";
    for (const auto &inElem: in)
        std::cout << " " << inElem;
    std::cout << "\n";

    auto out = makeVecOfVecs<int>(in, 5);

    // Output of result for validation.

    std::cout << "Output:\n";
    for (const auto &outElem1: out) {
        std::cout << "   ";
        for (const auto &outElem2: outElem1)
            std::cout << " " << outElem2;
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

A few sample runs are shown below for validation (you'll see I've asked for a chunk size of `10` rather than `5`, that's just to use less space in the answer):

```
pax:~> for i in "" 22 20 0 -9 1; do ./testprog ${i}; done

Input (17): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
Output:
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    11 12 13 14 15 16 17

Input (22): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
Output:
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
    21 22

Input (20): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
Output:
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

Input (0):
Output:

Input (-9):
Output:

Input (1): 1
Output:
    1
```

Comment: If you do `out.emplace_back(in.begin() + i, in.begin() + i + sz);` then the temporary `newVec` isn't needed.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I incorporated that as a comment in the code. I'm not sure there's *too* much advantage given the propensity of C++ to create temporaries anyway, and turn them in to non-temporaries, with seeming abandon, but it does make the code cleaner :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the vector of vectors is interpreted as a matrix, the first n-1 rows can be filled in a straightforward way by copying segments from the one-dimensional input vector. Only the last row of that "matrix" requires some attention, as it may not be completely filled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  // create initial data
  int vecSize = 17;
  std::vector<int> inVec(vecSize);
  std::iota(inVec.begin(), inVec.end(), 1);  

  // prepare new container
  int ncol = 5;
  int nrow = std::ceil(float(vecSize) / float(ncol));  
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> outVecVec(nrow);

  // row-wise copy
  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
    int rowLength = ncol;
    if (i == nrow - 1 && vecSize % ncol != 0) {
      rowLength = vecSize % ncol; // length of last row, if not filled      
    }
    outVecVec[i].resize(rowLength);
    auto vecIndex = inVec.begin() + i * ncol;
    std::copy(vecIndex, vecIndex + rowLength, outVecVec[i].begin());
  }

  // print output  
   for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
     for (int j = 0; j < outVecVec[i].size(); ++j)
       std::cout << outVecVec[i][j] << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}
```

demo: https://godbolt.org/z/w9aDrE

Answer (score 0):

Using the `range-v3` library this becomes very simple, and readable:

```
std::vector<int> v = ...
int m = ...

auto vs = v | ranges::views::chunk(m) 
            | ranges::to<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d_A2NZ).